# how can I make a s3 bucket sub images iteration generic

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rekognition

my bucket on s3 is named as 'python' and its subfolder is  'boss' . So I want to get all images of folder boss in lambda function. currently I am hard-coding values but putting image in root not in subfolder.

```
bucket="python"
key="20180530105812.jpeg"
```

then I want to call this function one by one for all images

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Get the object from the event
    bucket="ais-django"
    key="20180530105812.jpeg"

    try:

        # Calls Amazon Rekognition IndexFaces API to detect faces in S3 object 
        # to index faces into specified collection

        response = index_faces(bucket, key)

        # Commit faceId and full name object metadata to DynamoDB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best thing what you can do , add s3 event notification as a trigger to lambda function and configure it for your prefix of object that is **"boss/"** in your case

[image: add trigger]

here prefix will be "boss/"

[image: prefix]

Then change your bucket and key to this in your code :

```
bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'].encode('utf8'))
```

With help of this , whenever object will be uploaded to your ***bucket*/boss/** path, your code will automatically fetch it and will run it doing your processing in code

With this your lambda will not require any hard-coded strings of bucket and key and will run automatically against image upload in your subfolder path.Further if you want only images to be processed , add **filter** pattern to be **.jpg , .jpeg , .png , etc**

Comment: perfect solution

Comment: what is key in there ?

Comment: Then change your bucket and key to this in your code    . where to change key ?

Comment: 'key' is automaticallly fetched when a new object is uploaded because we used s3 event notification as trigger

Comment: Configuration is ambiguously defined. Cannot have overlapping suffixes in two rules if the prefixes are overlapping for the same event type. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: 562299C942F65845; S3 Extended Request ID: y6QMiq513oYJkgy7g7EqFDInubvM1ux9oRrFzPbAvPyfqyrCpNm9TMKPWJBk47+tbImt8Z8LxFk=)

Comment: Your two different lambda functions have same trigger configured . E.g , event notification on same path in s3 bucket

Comment: Change your configuration of  lambda environment

Comment: Mausam done that  :)  . I need a small help in other matter . can you tell a small solution please ?

Answer (score 1):

Use list_object operation on s3 Client.

```
bucket="python"
client=boto3.client('s3')
response = client.list_objects(
    Bucket=bucket,
    Prefix='boss'
)
numberofobjects=len(response['Contents'])
for x in range(1, numberofobjects):
    try:
        response2=index_faces(bucket, response['Contents'][x]['Key'])
```

Comment: hi , there is small edit . How I can Pass this one by one to  response = index_faces(bucket, key)  ?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter that folder within your bucket. As an example:

```
#import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
python_bucket = s3.Bucket('python')

for images in python_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="boss/"):
    print images.key
```

UPDATE:

According to your recent edit, you can iterate through the bucket/folder and run your script. This is a more complete snippet that should works well for your Lambda function:

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    images = ""
    python_bucket = s3.Bucket('python')

    #Here, you're going through each image in your bucket/folder.
    for image in python_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="boss/"):
        images += image.key

    return images
```